# How do I set documentroot for apache with puppet?

Tags: apache, puppet, vagrant

I've been trying to get apache to serve from /vagrant/ using puppet through vagrant, my manifest looks like this:

```
class apache {
  exec { 'apt-get update':
    command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update'
  }

  package { "apache2":
    ensure => present,
  }

  service { "apache2":
    ensure => running,
    require => Package["apache2"],
    root => '/vagrant/'
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate the help.... I'm stunned at how bad the manifest documentation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `service` resource manages the process but doesn't have anything to do with the configuration files. 
Your manifest simply says "Make sure that apt is updated, apache2 is installed and running".

I think what you are looking for can be handled with templates (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html).

Comment: I see, didn't realise it had that seperation, that explains why none of the tutorials addressed that stuff. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

easier than changing the httpd.conf with templates etc, it's to make a symlink from /var/www to /vagrant. Add

```
 file { '/var/www':
   ensure => 'link',
   target => '/vagrant',
   force => true,
}
```

to your puppet file and you are running.

Comment: This change will work in debian releases, but seems to fail in centos because yum fails to unpack some files to the shared folder.